# Wake from suspend on network activity - not WOL magic packet

Tags: 20.04, suspend, wakeonlan

Using Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

Can I suspend this machine based on no network activity for a period of time and then wake from suspend mode when network activity (ping?) is received?

The hardware supports this because the same machine has XP installed and working but can't see what I need to set in Ubuntu to do this. The idea is to have an always-on file/media server which drops down to suspend mode when not in use for power saving.

Edit: This is not a duplicate of the previously linked question which is about waking a machine with a WOL magic packet. I am asking if a machine can be resumed from suspend by a normal network packet or ping?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wake my PC with any packet, not just a magic packet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580931/how-to-wake-my-pc-with-any-packet-not-just-a-magic-packet)

Comment: See [this closed question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303206/wake-on-networkactivity-can-it-be-made-to-work-on-ubuntu) from yesterday. I am *not* voting to close this, merely linking to it for reference.